# how to handle lists and arrays with varying length?

Tags: python, arrays, list, vectorization, variable-length

I have the following code:

```
ray_points = [np.array([r1_1, r2_1, r3_1, r4_1]),np.array([r1_2, r2_2, r3_2, r4_2]),np.array([r1_3, r2_3, r3_3, r4_3])]
```

The list `ray_points` contains the coordinates of light rays. For this example, I have four light rays (r1,r2,r3,r4). Each time after I've located the next coordinates for the light rays (they have 'new' coordinates once they travel and hit another surfaces), I will append the list `ray_points` with a new array of size (4L,3L), (4L stands for the four light rays, 3L stands for the three spacial coordinates). So for example, r1_2 is an array with length three and means the 2nd coordinates of ray r1, r3_3 means the 3rd coordinates of ray r3, and so on.

My previous approach is to have N different lists, each contains the coordinates using arrays with shape (3L,1L), for N different rays. Now I use a (4L,3L) array to store all the coordinates of the light rays for each new intersection because I want to 'vectorize' my code in order to speed things up. (Imagine if I have like 100k light rays). Everytime when I want to calculate the next coordinates, next refracted directions, etc, I will just past the most previous coordinates of the ray, which is simple `ray_points[-1]` to my functions and the functions to calculate everything directly to this array, which is really significantly faster than what I did previously by creating N different lists and looping each light ray for calculation.

Now the problem is that, if different rays have different number of intersection of surfaces, and hence different number of new coordinates, I run into trouble. For instance, ray r1 has refracted 10 times is already terminated, so I will only have r1_1, r1_2 ... r1_10. But I still need to keep track of other rays r2,r3,r4. Since I use a single 4X3 array that contains my coordinates for the 4 rays, I have to keep adding coordinates to r1. I can use keep the new points/directions of r1 the same, but then I am just wasting memory, and imagine if all the rays are terminated and I have a single ray that is keep travelling and having new coordinates, then most of the elements of `ray_points` are actually redundant.

I would like to know how I should set up my initial codes so that I can use this vectorized approach to speed things up, yet I can still keep the advantage of the original approach - treat each ray separately so I can handle rays with different number of new coordinates.

Comment: I read your second and third paragraphs about four times, and even though I am an optical physicist and a python programmer I must say I haven't the slightest idea what you are asking.  Try restating the problem in strictly computer science language.

Comment: I tried my best to explain it more clearly. see if the new version helps you understanding my question

Comment: May I recommend abstracting you question. Ignore your unique problem and ask what kind of data structure it is that you'd like to form. Regardless of rays etc... I'm having a hard time understanding what you want from what you have. Just my 2 cents

Comment: I ask a new question here, which should be much more precise and clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115993/efficient-way-of-appending-extracting-list-elements